# Bind content control depends on user click button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am writing a wpf application and implements mvvm light tool. The GUI looks like: 
[image]

Every time when a user click on button, it should change the content on the right side, marked with red border. The XAML code:

```
<igWpf:XamRibbonWindow x:Class="BackupCustomizing.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
        xmlns:ig="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:BackupCustomizing.Views"
        xmlns:igWpf="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml/wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
        Height="400"
        Width="700"
        Title="Backup customizing V0.1"
        DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" ResizeMode="NoResize">

    <igWpf:XamRibbonWindow.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type views:ServerView}"></DataTemplate>
    </igWpf:XamRibbonWindow.Resources>

    <ig:ThemeManager.Theme>
        <ig:Office2013Theme />
    </ig:ThemeManager.Theme>
    <igWpf:RibbonWindowContentHost x:Name="_content"
                                   Theme="Office2013"
                                   igWpf:RibbonWindowContentHost.ApplicationAccentColor="#0072C6">
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <views:NavigationView Grid.Column="0"/>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>

    </igWpf:RibbonWindowContentHost>
</igWpf:XamRibbonWindow>
```

and the code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using BackupCustomizing.ViewModel;
using Infragistics.Themes;
using Infragistics.Windows.Ribbon;

namespace BackupCustomizing
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : XamRibbonWindow
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Initializes a new instance of the MainWindow class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Closing += (s, e) => ViewModelLocator.Cleanup();

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the code above, I tried with:

```
<igWpf:XamRibbonWindow.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type views:ServerView}"></DataTemplate>
</igWpf:XamRibbonWindow.Resources>
```

and the content presenter:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

and here I stocked, how to continue?

The ViewModel code:

```
using BackupCustomizing.Model;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;

namespace BackupCustomizing.ViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     This class contains properties that the main View can data bind to.
    ///     <para>
    ///         See http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm
    ///     </para>
    /// </summary>
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        private readonly IDataService _dataService;
        private string _welcomeTitle = string.Empty;

        /// <summary>
        ///     Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
        {
            _dataService = dataService;
            _dataService.GetData(
                (item, error) =>
                {

                });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you code working in minimum changes

```
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        private readonly IDataService _dataService;
        private string _welcomeTitle = string.Empty;
        private ViewModelBase detailsViewModel = null;
        public ViewModelBase DetailsViewModel{
           get { return detailsViewModel;}
           set { detailsViewModel = value; RaisePropertyChanged("DetailsViewModel"); }
        }
        /// <summary>
        ///     Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
        {
            _dataService = dataService;
            _dataService.GetData(
                (item, error) =>
                {
                   detailsViewModel = new ServerViewModel(item); //ViewModel for the ServerView
                });
        }
    }

<igWpf:XamRibbonWindow.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ServerViewModel}">
       <views:ServerView />
    </DataTemplate>
</igWpf:XamRibbonWindow.Resources>

<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding DetailsViewModel}" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

There are other techniques to do MVVM, I am just showing the way to do it with the approach you have started with. Problem with this approach is that it will not scale well to large number of views in the ContentPresenter.

Comment: First of all, thanks very much for help. Please show me, how to build for large application.

Comment: Please take a look at these repositories: https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui and applications built using this source. The microsoft guidance for WPF MVVM based applications is at https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/. This repository also has some sample applications which is built using the best practices that can be used for building a large scale enterprise applications. For the compositewpf you should be able to find the articles describing the examples on msdn.